# Getting physical device sensor output with Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm Trying to develop a program with Qt Creator 5.1.1 for android that can get output of three sensors (QAccelerometer,Qtilt,Qmagnetometer) of physical device (HTC One x)
Everything is ok , but there is an issue that when i want to show the output in the textlabel , the output disappear very quickly and it is turning to zero.
Here is My MainWindow.cpp :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QTimer *timer;
    timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::update(){


//----------------------TiltSensor--------------///////
    QSensor sensor("QTiltSensor");
    sensor.start();
    QSensorReading *reading = sensor.reading();
    qreal xrotation = reading->property("xRotation").value<qreal>();
    qreal yrotation = reading->property("yRotation").value<qreal>();

//---------------QMagnetometer-------------------/////////


    QSensor sensor2("QMagnetometer");
    sensor2.start();
    QSensorReading *reading2 = sensor2.reading();
    qreal xmagnet = reading2->property("x").value<qreal>();
    qreal ymagnet = reading2->property("y").value<qreal>();
    qreal zmagnet = reading2->property("z").value<qreal>();

//----------------------QAccelerometer--------------------------/////


    QSensor sensor3("QAccelerometer");
    sensor3.start();
    QSensorReading *reading3 = sensor3.reading();
    qreal xAccel = reading3->property("x").value<qreal>();
    qreal yAccel = reading3->property("y").value<qreal>();
    qreal zAccel = reading3->property("z").value<qreal>();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------///




    {
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(xrotation));
    ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(yrotation));

    }

    {
            ui->label_10->setText(QString::number(xmagnet));
            ui->label_8->setText(QString::number(ymagnet));
            ui->label_11->setText(QString::number(zmagnet));
    }


    {
            ui->label_17->setText(QString::number(xAccel));
            ui->label_16->setText(QString::number(yAccel));
            ui->label_15->setText(QString::number(zAccel));
    }
    }
```

i googled a lot and reading every document in Qt-Help but got nothing , i even try to use readychange() signal but it doesn't seem to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After you run sensor start you need to wait. You should probably start the sensor in you constructor and connect the signal `readingChanged` to your slot. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Old post but maybe people still have the same issue.
change the name of your function from `update()` to `updateVals()` for example.
`update()` is reserved and it will give you issues without warning you about it.